# Uncompress batch of "tar.gz" files in a folder

Tags: python

There is a folder which contain several "tar.gz" files. I want to uncompress these files. I write python code below. But it reports error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'DT_20180322.tar.gz'. I wonder why I have this error and how to correct it? Thanks!

```
import tarfile
files = [f for f in os.listdir('TE-xy/')]
for fname in files: 
    if fname.endswith("tar.gz"):
        tar = tarfile.open(fname, "r:gz")
        tar.extractall()
        tar.close()
```

Comment: "print" debugging will be your best way forward here. SO is a terrible debugger. You also don't say under what conditions you see the failure. Is this the only failure? One of many? All files fail? (Almost certainly this is because you are enumerating filenames in a subdirectory but operating on them as if they were in the current directory.)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are just using the filename.

You need to include the directory name as well.

```
import os
import tarfile

files = [f for f in os.listdir('TE-xy/')]
for fname in files: 
    if fname.endswith("tar.gz"):
        fpath = os.path.join('TE-xy', fname)
        tar = tarfile.open(fpath, "r:gz")
        tar.extractall()
        tar.close()
```